# Load pretty printed JSON from file into python?

Tags: python, json, io, pretty-print, jsonschema

I have a large JSON document stored in a pretty-print format to file, where the file looks like:

```
$ nano data.json

{
"type" : "object",
"properties" : {
  "price" : {"type" : "number"},
  "name" : {"type" : "string"},
  },
}
```

The traditional ways I've found for reading such json files, such as...

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as handle:
    data = json.load(handle)
```

and...

```
json_data=open('data.json','r')
data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()
```

and...

```
data = []
with open('data.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

and...

```
ss = ''
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ss += ''.join(line.strip())

data = json.loads(ss.decode("utf-8","replace"))
```

...seem to only work for single-string, not pretty-print formatted JSON.

How would I load JSON of this format from a file?  The errors I keep getting when trying these formats are...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 250 (char 250)

ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 9 column 13 (char 310)
```

Comment: You have invalid JSON; there should *not* be a trailing comma there. The pretty-printing is not the issue here.

Comment: Really?  I pulled this json from the jsonschema documentation: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema They have the comma.

Comment: They define a **python** dictionary, where the comma is fine. Python and JSON may look alike, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: Yep, you are right.  I guess I'll leave this up as "Here are a bunch of ways to load valid JSON"  Thanks again, Martijn.

Comment: Not sure that people will find this as such; there are plenty of other Python / JSON questions already here that you could be seen as a dupe of in that case. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else finding this in the future googling things similar to what I did when I posted this---you may think your error is in the loading, but mine as above was actually in the JSON itself, rather than the loading (as Martijn Pieters pointed out).  I was copying the schema from the jsonschema python project---but this, it turned out, was not JSON, but a deceptively similar-looking python dictionary.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem, reasons were the same — I had single quotes instead of double quotes (keep forgetting that) and something else similar.